# Деление слов на слоги

Tags: фонетика, фонетический-разбор

Задание: разбейте дефисами на слоги слова "праздник", "контрольная", "майский"

праз-дник, конт-ро-льная

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует несколько равноправных вариантов разбора. В традиции Московской школы, например, верно:

- пра–здник;
- кон–троль–на–я;
- май–ский.

Если вам нужна какая-то определенная традиция, напишите.